# How do you arrive at the second form of the 1st order integrated rate law?

Tags: kinetics

As I understand it, the first-order integrated rate law is:

$$\ln[\ce{A}] = \ln[\ce{A}]_0 - k t$$

However, I'm also told that this can be expressed as a ratio of $[\ce{A}]_0$ and $[\ce{A}]$, as follows

$$\ln \left(\frac{[\ce{A}]_0}{[\ce{A}]\,\,}\right) = kt$$

How did they arrive at this expression of the integrated rate law?  I don't see a way to arrive at it algebraically, unless I'm greatly missing something.

Comment: This is just using logarithm rule $\log(a/b) = \log(a)-\log(b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to ln([A0]/[A])=kt from ln[A]=−kt+ln[A]0 just requires some understandings of log properties and a few log rules.

First rearrange ln[A]=−kt+ln[A]0

to

kt = ln[A]0 - ln[A]

From there, the log rule
log(a/b)=log(a)−log(b) means that you can state this as

kt = ln([A]0/[A])